# Symfony 4.2 validating empty float fields for entity

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I am trying to write validator for form which has string and float types.
If I am creating a new object, which was not stored to database, everything works fine. But if I am editing an object which was stored in database and I set string or float value to empty I am getting

```
Expected argument of type "float", null given at property path "price"
```

errors.

A workaround for string field was setting

```
'empty_data' => '',
```

or creating a data transformer as such

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class NullToEmptyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Does not transform anything.
     *
     * @param string|null $value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a null to an empty string.
     *
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (\is_null($value)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

But this can not be applied to float field. What is the best solution for validating empty float fields, which previously had a value in database?

EDIT:
I found out the solution. The problem was in Entity setters. It was expecting only float, so I had to change parameter type to ?float .

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use Asserts for that? First, you need to install annotations

```
 composer require symfony/validator doctrine/annotations
```

When you want to use it on entity, Import it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

And this is how you have to use on property of entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Length(min=3)
 */
private $firstName;
```

Those are some examples of asserts:

```
* @Assert\Type(type="string")

* @Assert\Type(type="float")

* @Assert\NotBlank()
```

For more information https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#properties

Comment: I forgot to mention. I am using Asserts, but the problem is that my application crashes at $editForm->handleRequest($request); and it does not reach isValid() part.

Comment: I am using it. I am getting 500 error and message "Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "float", "NULL" given at property path "minimumSum"." at /vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php line 173"

Comment: Need to install annotations? God forbid no. You don’t need any annotations. This is blasphemy, madness.

Comment: @emix what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The asker updated his question with an answer that worked for me as well to address the error that he was getting:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "float", "NULL" given at property path...

I had initially read over his edit remark because the solution presented there was not given in any answer or comment:

> The problem was in the field's setter. It was expecting only float, so I had to change parameter type to ?float

Since the setter did not accept null values, an exception was thrown instead of a validation error.
To explain this: The setter needs to be able to accept all possible values coming from the form so that the validation will be triggered.

My working code example that with the question mark in place is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"selling"})
 * @Assert\PositiveOrZero(groups={"selling"})
 * @Assert\Type(type="float", groups={"selling"})
 */
private $price;

public function setPrice(?float $price): self
{
    $this->price = round($price,2);

    return $this;
}
```